# Angle for reverse dumbbell flyes

Tags: weightlifting, deltoids

What is the best beach incline *angle* for reverse dumbbell flyes for rear delt?

Answer (score 1):

Most times, when you ask yourself "what's the best [some detail] to perform [some exercise] with?", the answer is usually none. You should be aiming for variety. Try flat, try a little bit of incline, and try more incline. You'll target the muscles in different ways, and guarantee yourself the right stimulation.